# Where to find the Visual C++ 6.0 CRT Source Code?

Tags: c++, msvc

I want to see MSVCRT's implementation details for the old Microsoft Visual Studio C++ 6.0 compiler. On newer Visual Studio versions, it is located in `/VC/crt/src/` directory, but there is no such directory for MSVC 6.0. Where can I find it?

Comment: You are almost right, but also slightly mistaken. The source code that you can find in modern MSVC is _not_ complete. There are some crucial parts missing. Also, at least for a long time, you needed the Professional edition to get the CRT sources at all.

Comment: I know, since MSVC is a proprietary product. Anyway, I have a copy of 1999 Visual C++ 6.0 Professional Edition and there was no CRT source code included.

Comment: Heh. VS6... that's like...super old....like, back when they gave out samples. Regardless, you can find it on the Enterprise CDs as part of the supplemental material which has been Archive.org'd (make sure to donate to them): VC98/CRT/SRC

Comment: @AliRizvi-Santiago could you post that as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPD.:** I found it. It is indeed in Visual Studio Professional installation CD drive.
[image: source]